# Specifying Task Resources: Fractional gpu

Tags: gpu, dask

Is there a way to specify a fractional gpu requirement for a task? In the [example](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html) at Dask webpage, it specifies a single GPU.

```
from distributed import Client
client = Client('scheduler:8786')

data = [client.submit(load, fn) for fn in filenames]
processed = [client.submit(process, d, resources={'GPU': 1}) for d in data]
final = client.submit(aggregate, processed, resources={'MEMORY': 70e9})
```

It will be a waste to allocate one GPU for a small model.

Ray library has a way of [doing this](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/using-ray-with-gpus.html#fractional-gpus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fractional resources are allowed.

In general, resources are arbitrary units, so if you instantiate the scheduler with "GPU=2" or some "foo=10", the scheduler will keep track of these resources during task assignment, but scheduler does not really know (or care) what "GPU" or "foo" is. When submitting tasks you can pass `{"GPU": 0.25}` and the scheduler will assign multiple tasks assigned to the GPU worker, For example, if the scheduler is told that each worker has `"foo=10"`, then the scheduler will ask each worker to run concurrently up to ten tasks submitted with `{"foo":1}`.